# How to pass more input params into a git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

Currently the git hook I have is 
curl -X POST  https://xyz.abc.com:9674/t/manipiya5.com/webapps/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=https://abc.com:8443/git/manipiya5.com/manipiya5app1.git

I want to pass a user name also as userName=manipiya@manipiya.com

How can I modify the curl command?
I tried the following, but the username was not passed to the backend.
curl -X POST  https://xyz.abc.com:9674/t/manipiya5.com/webapps/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=https://abc.com:8443/git/manipiya5.com/manipiya5app1.git&tenantUserName=manipiya5@manipiya5.com

Tried even with the below, but was not successful. 
curl -X POST curl -X POST  https://xyz.abc.com:9674/t/manipiya5.com/webapps/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=https://abc.com:8443/git/manipiya5.com/manipiya5app1.git -d 'tenantUserName=manipiya5@manipiya5.com'

Please help ASAP.

Comment: Is this a git question ? a curl question ? or a question on how your specific web service works ?

Comment: This is a Git specific question. Need to know how to send extra params to a curl command in a GIT hook

Answer (score 0):

This kind of input should probably be set using environment variables

Comment: Thanks LeGEC. 
I dont understand your point. This is a groovy script and I have the userName as a variable in my script. I want to know how to pass the userName variable.